# WKWebView localHTMLString doesn't seem to work on iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a very simple call in my WKWebView and nothing is displayed

```
   webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body>test</body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

If I replace this with , WKWebView renders the web Page fine

```
  webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NURL("www.bing.com"))
```

Any reason why loadHTMLString is not able to render a very simple HTML string?
I know there are limitations of WKWebView from rendering local files, but this is the html string and I can't imaging what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the navigationDelegate method

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) { }
```

I was returning decisionHandler(.Cancel) if the scheme isn't http. For loadHTMLString, scheme is returned as "" and hence the navigation was being cancelled